# angularjs child directive DOM doesn't load fast enough

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile

Hi I have nested directives where I have a parent directive along with its child directives which can be transcluded.  My problem is when try to find some dom elements in the parent link function it doesn't return an array unless I set a timeout.  It appears the child rendering/transclusion isn't happening fast enough.  So is there a way to solve this without using a timeout and then calling find the child elements?

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', [])
.run(function($templateCache){
  $templateCache.put('innerPane.html', "<div class='inner-pane' ng-transclude></div>");

  $templateCache.put('slidePaneSelector.html', "<div class='slide-pane'><inner-pane><h2>First Inner Pane</h2></inner-pane><inner-pane><h2>Second Inner Pane</h2></inner-pane></div>");
})
.directive('innerPane', function(){
 return {
  restrict: 'EA',
  transclude: true,
  replace: true,
  templateUrl: 'innerPane.html',
  scope:{},
  link: function(scope,element,attr){

  }
 }
})
.directive('slidePaneSelector', ['$timeout',function($timeout){
 return {
  restrict: 'EA',
  transclude: true,
  replace: true,
  templateUrl: 'slidePaneSelector.html',
  scope:{},
  link: function(scope,element,attr){

   var firstPaneElement = angular.element(element.find('div')[0]);
   var secondPaneElement = angular.element(element.find('div')[1]);
   
   console.log(element.find('div'));  

      $timeout(function(){
          console.log(element.find('div'));
      },100);
  
  }
 }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.28"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    
    <slide-pane-selector></slide-pane-selector>
  </body>

</html>
```

Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/sS5cSMboSV2mjlRxsgO8?p=preview

Comment: the timeout is not there for time but rather to wait for the digest to be over. even if you do a $timeout for 0 millisecond your find will work. This is because $timeout waits for the current digest to be over before executing. Having said this I do not know a work around :(

Comment: changing it to 0 doesn't work

Comment: it does. http://plnkr.co/edit/Ctrbbn0G2Dq8bbUBlAw7?p=preview

Comment: @user3226075, did the below answer address your question?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `$timeout` without the time component - it would wait to the end of the $digest cycle and execute.

The proper way, I think, is to have the child directive "register" with the parent. This is done with `require: "^parent"` and by exposing some `register` method on a controller of the parent.

```
.directive("parent", function(){
  return {
    controller: function($scope, $element){
       this.registerChild = function(childElement){
          // do whatever you need here
       }
    }
  }
}

.directive("child", function(){
  return {
    require: "^parent",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, parentCtrl){
       parentCtrl.registerChild(element);
    }
  }
}
```